# The Cantor set and ternary expansions

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, cantor-set

I'm trying to prove that the Cantor set $\mathcal{C}$ contains all numbers $x \in [0,1]$ with ternary expansion $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{3^k}$, such that $a_k=0$ or $a_k=2$. I'm going by induction, proving that $x$ belongs to every $\mathcal{C}_k$, where $\mathcal{C} = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal{C}_k$, and $\mathcal{C}_k$ is the usual $k$-th set in the construction of the Cantor set (i.e., a disjoint union of $2^k$ closed intervals, each of length $\frac{1}{3^k}$, etc.).

Here's my work so far:

The base case, $k=1$, was easy: If $a_1=0$, then the geometric sum yields $x \leq \frac{1}{3}$; similarly, if $a_1=2$, then $x \geq \frac{2}{3}$.

For the inductive step, I assume $x \in \mathcal{C}_k$, and try to prove $x \in \mathcal{C}_{k+1}$. First, I assume there is an interval $[a,b]$ of length $\frac{1}{3^k}$ containing $x$, where $[a,b]$ is one of the $2^k$ intervals that make up $\mathcal{C}_k$. I can write $[a,b]$ as

$$
[a,b] = \left[a, a + \frac{1}{3^{k+1}} \right] \cup \left( a + \frac{1}{3^{k+1}},  b - \frac{1}{3^{k+1}} \right) \cup \left[ b- \frac{1}{3^{k+1}}, b \right],
$$

and of course I'd like to show, for instance, that $x$ is in the leftmost of these intervals if $a_{k+1} = 0$. The geometric sum gives me the bound $x \leq \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{a_j}{3^j} + \frac{1}{3^{k+1}}$, but I want $x \leq a + \frac{1}{3^{k+1}}$.

I've tried and failed to get past here. I feel like I'm missing something silly, but can anybody help me reach finish off the argument?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close indeed.  What you are trying to prove follows from the fact that actually 
$$a = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{a_j}{3^j}$$

You may want to strength your statement to include that $C_k$ contains intervals whose LHS endpoints are of that form.  Then you could directly use it in your inductive step.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense to me that $a$ should equal that sum; but I'm not sure how to go about showing it...

Comment: @Bachmaninoff  Why not define your intervals $\mathcal{C_k}$ that way.  Then there is nothing to show, you would just refer to your definition.

Comment: If you aren't comfortable with that, you can first show that the construction of iteratively "removing middle thirds" precisely creates intervals whose LHS have a value of that form.  Again by induction.

Comment: I think I get it now; thanks for your help!